# How to hide all buttons using foreach?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

Follow code:

```
FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Button_1).Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Button_2).Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.Button_3).Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
...
```

Follow picture:

[image]

In the first line is to hide a "button 1" and I have more than 50 buttons. I do not want to copy this whole line and do up to 50 times, it's very tiring. Is there a way to loop using `foreach` or to hide all those buttons?

Is it possible to hide buttons 1 through 50 using foreach?

Comment: First of all why are you having 50 buttons separately. Use a Container list if possible . If you can not use `List`  then just run a for loop on parent layout children and hide all.

Comment: @ADM **First of all why are you having 50 buttons separately ?** It's just a test.

Comment: well then test with right approach . Even a normal calculator does not have 50 scattered buttons.

Comment: @ADM, Please see the photo as I did. http://abhiandroid-8fb4.kxcdn.com/ui/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/ScrollView-In-Android.jpg

Comment: @ADM I have multiple buttons with `scrollview`

Comment: That should be  a ListView . Apart from this i have stated the solution above . You need to loop through the child have a look at https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18777/get-all-child-views-of-root.

Comment: @ADM, Thanks for the link, I'll see.

Comment: if you have all this button in a parent view you can use the view group method on the parent of it to hide all buttons using foreach for all button whose view group is found to be buttons

Comment: Have you solved the problem? if not i have the solution for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having 50 buttons inside the scrollview please have a Listview and place buttons in your listview.  (See end of answer for solving with scrollview and buttons)

Create a model class Button :

```
public class Button{

public bool isVisible;
}
```

In your activity create a List of this class.
List buttonList = new List();

Then create a custom adapter for list and set this list as the source for the ListView.

Once done, just update the objects in list. In adapter based on the value of the boolean, just show/hide the buttons

This way it will be easy to enable or disable buttons in any combination. Else your code will be messed up.

However if you still want to have Scrollview and fifity buttons,
Then in activity iterate through the scrollview like this.

I'm assuming you have scrollview inside LinearLayout, I'm passing the LinearLayout as method parameter inside which your scrollview resides :

```
 public void updateButtonVisibility(LinearLayout layout) {
        for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View v = layout.getChildAt(i);
            if (view instanceof Button) {
                //Hide Button
                view.Visibility = View.Gone;
            }
        }
}
```